# How to navigate from Mainviewcontroller to another view controller using SlideMenuViewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I'm trying to navigate from MainViewController to other ViewController when clicked on the **rightHeaderButtonClicked** method. But, it doesn't navigate. I have shared the code below.

**Appdelegate.swift**

```
class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {

    var window: UIWindow?

    fileprivate func createMenuView() {
        // create viewController code...
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let mainViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        let menuViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MenuViewController") as! MenuViewController
        let nvc: UINavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: mainViewController)
        menuViewController.mainViewController = nvc

        let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController:mainViewController, leftMenuViewController: menuViewController)
        slideMenuController.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = true
        slideMenuController.delegate = mainViewController
        slideMenuController.removeRightGestures()

        self.window?.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 236.0, green: 238.0, blue: 241.0, alpha: 1.0)
        self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }

    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        createMenuView()
        return true
    }

    func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
        // Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method to pause the game.
    }

    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Use this method to release shared resources, save user data, invalidate timers, and store enough application state information to restore your application to its current state in case it is terminated later.
        // If your application supports background execution, this method is called instead of applicationWillTerminate: when the user quits.
    }

    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called as part of the transition from the background to the active state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the background.
    }

    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
        // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    }
}
```

**MainViewController.swift**

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController,SlideMenuControllerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var chitsTableView: UITableView!

    var mainVc: UIViewController!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        chitsTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ChitTableViewCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "ChitTableViewCell")
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.slideMenuController()?.changeMainViewController(self.allbiddersViewController, close: true)
        self.navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        self.slideMenuController()?.addLeftGestures()
    }

    @IBAction func leftHeaderButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.slideMenuController()?.openLeft()
    }

    @IBAction func rightHeaderButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        let chitdetailVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChitDetailViewController") as! ChitDetailViewController
        self.slideMenuController()?.navigationController?.pushViewController(chitdetailVc, animated: true)
    }
}
```

*I am unable to understand the hierarchy of SlideMenuViewController and the viewcontroller stack prints nil always.*

Comment: There's not enough information here to give you an answer. There is no code above for ExSlideMenuController. Is this something you wrote, or something open source?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift.
However, I don't think that's your issue here.
I think the problem is with your setup of the UINavigationController.
Instead of setting the mainViewContoller as a property of the `ExSlideViewController`, you should use the navigation controller that contains it:

```
let slideMenuController = ExSlideMenuController(mainViewController: nvc, leftMenuViewController: menuViewController)
```

Then, you can push directly in the MainViewController, instead of having to call the parent `slideMenuController`:

```
@IBAction func rightHeaderButtonClicked(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
    let chitdetailVc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ChitDetailViewController") as! ChitDetailViewController
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(chitdetailVc, animated: true)
 }
```